# Is a java synchronized method entry point thread safe enough?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, shared-resource

I have a Singleton class handling a kind of cache with different objects in a Hashmap.
(The format of a key is directly linked to the type of object stored in the map - hence the map is of )

Three different actions are possible on the map : add, get, remove.

I secured the access to the map by using a public entry point method (no intense access) :

```
public synchronized Object doAction(String actionType, String key, Object data){
  Object myObj = null;
  if (actionType.equalsIgnorecase("ADD"){
    addDataToMyMap(key,data);
  } else if (actionType.equalsIgnorecase("GET"){
    myObj = getDataFromMyMap(key);
  } else if (actionType.equalsIgnorecase("REM"){  
    removeDataFromMyMap(key);      
  }
  return myObj;
}
```

Notes:

The map is private. Methods addDataToMyMap(), getDataFromMyMap() and removeDataFromMyMap() are private. Only the entry point method is public and nothing else except the static getInstance() of the class itself.

Do you confirm it is thread safe for concurrent access to the map since there is no other way to use map but through that method ?

If it is safge for a Map, I guess this principle could be applied to any other kind of shared ressource.

Many thanks in advance for your answers.

David

Comment: I assume you mean doAction to be a synchronized method?  (It's not in your snippet.)

Comment: Do you have `synchronized` keyword on the 3 methods: addDataIn... , etc.?

Comment: indeed - corrected.
The other methods are private and are not direclty synchronized themselves

Comment: this means that your threads will be able to add,get or remove only one thread at the time, not the best solution i have to say.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to make cache methods unsynchronized and make entry point synchronized because in case you can perform anly one operation

Comment: As I precised. There is not much use of the map but it has to remain safe as shared ressource. I might change to a synchronized Map implementation in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see your implementation of your methods, but it could be enough.
BUT i would recommend you to use a Map from the Collection API of java then you wouldnt need to synchronize your method unless your sharing some other instance.

read this: http://www.java-examples.com/get-synchronized-map-java-hashmap-example

Comment: Using a synchronized version of a map, may not still be enough.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your class will be thread safe as long as the only entry point is doAction.

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed the synchronized keyword

Comment: To be more specific, even if you move the synchronized keyword away from doAction() to specific methods like removeDataFromMyMap(), it won't be sufficient. The above will give you some small performance penalty(micro second level), since you are synchronizing at the entry public method level, but will guarentee you thread safety. Once I benchmarked the performance of ConcurrentHashMap vs the synchronized{hashmap}. 70th percentile came around 15 micros - ConcurrentHashMap is faster when multiple threads access it rather than synchronizing the hashmap like the way you did.

Comment: thanks, that was the point. I just added a note - yes this is the only entry point

Answer (score 1):

If your `cache` class has private `HashMap` and you have three methods and all are `public synchronized` and not `static` and if you don't have any other `public` instance variable then i think your cache is `thread-safe`.

Better to post your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely safe. As long as all the threads are accessing it using a common lock, which in this case is the Object, then it's thread-safe. (Other answers may be more performant but your implementation is safe.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.synchronizedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) to synchronize access to the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

As is it is hard to determine if the code is thread safe. Important information missing from your example are:

1. Are the methods public
2. Are the methods synchronized
3. It the map only accessed through the methods

I would advice you to look into [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) to get a grasp of the problems and how to tackle them. Exploring the [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class would give further information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). It offers better throughput than synchronized doAction and better thread safety than Collections.synchronizedMap().

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your code.  As someone else stated, you can use Collections.synchronizedMap.   However, this only synchronizes the individual method calls on the map.  So if:

```
map.get(key);
map.put(key,value);
```

Are executed at the same time in two different threads, one will block until the other exits.  However, if your critical section is larger than the single call into the map:

```
SomeExpensiveObject value = map.get(key);
if (value == null) {
   value = new SomeExpensiveObject();
   map.put(key,value);
}
```

Now let's assume the key is not present.  The first thread executes, and gets a null value back.  The scheduler yields that thread, and runs thread 2, which also gets back a null value. 
It constructs the new object and puts it in the map.  Then thread 1 resumes and does the same, since it still has a null value.

This is where you'd want a larger synchronization block around your critical section

```
SomeExpensiveObject value = null;

synchronized (map) {
  value = map.get(key);
  if (value == null) {
     value = new SomeExpensiveObject();
     map.put(key,value);
  }
}
```